# context click in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting Unsupported Command Exception for the below piece of Selenium Webdriver code. I tried to google out the options for context click and I am able to see that the code I had written is correct with respect to context click.

Please help me in understanding as to what I am missing here.

```
package DataProvider;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
public class UISelect {

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/Madankumar/Desktop/Gecko Driver/geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            WebElement oWE=driver.findElement(By.linkText("About"));

            Actions oAction=new Actions(driver);
            oAction.moveToElement(oWE);
            oAction.contextClick(oWE).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem using Action chains in Selenium with Firefox using Geckodriver, and it was due to this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178#c1
 If it's just sendKeys you can send each one individually. The command I had depended on the Actions, so I solved it by using executeScript to send the command using javascript instead.

The following code samples are from:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations

You can execute arbitrary javascript to find an element and as long as you return a DOM Element, it will be automatically converted to a WebElement object.

Simple example on a page that has jQuery loaded:

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('.cheese')[0]");
```

Finding all the inputs on every page:

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
List<WebElement> inputs = (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "var labels = arguments[0], inputs = []; for (var i=0; i < labels.length; i++){" +
    "inputs.push(document.getElementById(labels[i].getAttribute('for'))); } return inputs;", labels);
```

SendKeys:

```
// Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please provide me the code snippet for sendKeys and execute_script.

Comment: answer edited with examples. execute_script is the python command. I changed it to executeScript the java command.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because Actions API is not implemented yet in geckodriver/marionette.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233